# How to get the value of a promise in an async / await function on typescript?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, promise, es6-promise

I have the following code:

```
export class AuthService {

  private key:string = "";

  constructor(private storage: Storage) {

  }

  private async getKey() {
    let response = await this.storage.get('key');
    return response;
  }

  public init() {
    this.key = this.getKey();
  }
}
```

But I get the following error: `type promise any is not assignable to type string`, the problem is with the return of getKey().

I want to set the value of this.key to the one stored on the Storage, I know I could use:

```
this.storage.get('key').then((val) => { this.key = val });
```

But I want to do it in a synchronous way.

Thank you very much

Comment: `init` is not an asynchronous function, so you cannot `await` a promise in there like you can in `getKey`. No, it's not possible to immediately (synchronously) get the result value of a promise, and `async function`s don't change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key` is a string. The return value of `getKey`, and all `async` functions, is a promise. You can't assign a promise to a string, as TypeScript is telling you. Instead, you have to wait for the promise (using `then`) and assign the value of the promise to `key`. So:

```
export class AuthService {

  private key:string = "";

  constructor(private storage: Storage) {

  }

  private async getKey() {
    let response = await this.storage.get('key');
    return response;
  }

  public init() {
    this.getKey().then(key => this.key = key);
  }
}
```

Or, you could make `init` itself an async function:

```
public async init() {
  this.key = await this.getKey();
}
```

but of course `this.key` still will not be populated until `this.getKey()` resolves, which won't be until `this.storage.get` resolves.

In many cases it will be better to "unwrap" the promise directly in the template, using the `async` pipe:

```
export class AuthService {

  public key: Promise<string>;

  constructor(private storage: Storage) { }

  ngOnInit() { this.key = this.storage.get('key'); }
}

// template

The key is {{key | async}}
```

> But I want to do it in a synchronous way.

You can't. There is no way to make something asynchronous into something synchronous, other than a time machine. If something is going to happen in the future--whether 100ms, or 100 years--you have to wait for it. That's true whether you wait for the promise with `promise.then()` or `await`. `await` does not magically transform the future into the present. It is merely syntactic sugar that allows you to write your code in a way which **looks** synchronous, with the follow-up logic coming directly after the `await`, instead of inside a `then` handler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, some comments and doubts: a. I don't use the value on the template so I can't use the `async` pipe. b. if await still returns a promise, what's the purpose of using it.

Comment: If you have a promise, you have to wait for it in any case. `await` is merely a syntax which allows you to wait for it and assign its value, if you want. `await a = promise(); ...` is precisely equivalent to `promise.then(a => ...)`. It's essentially syntactic sugar. `await` cannot make something asynchronous into something synchronous. Nothing can.